# Enable/Disable deleted from shinyjs?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I tried searching release notes or issues about this but couldn't find any... 
It seems that the functions enable/disable from shinyjs are not working. I thought that the problem might be code, but show/hide are working fine. So my question is if these functions have been deprecated?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('in1', 'in1', choices = c('a','b'),
                selected = 'a', multiple = TRUE),
    dateInput('in2', label = 'in2'),

    actionButton('process', 'Process'),
    downloadButton('download', 'Download')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent( input$process, {
      shinyjs::enable('download')
      # shinyjs::show('download')
    })
    observe({
      input$in1
      input$in2
      shinyjs::disable('download')
      # shinyjs::hide('download')
    })

    # edit
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        date <- format(Sys.Date(), '%Y%m%d')
        paste0(date, ' - test.csv') }, 
      content = function(file) {
        write.table(1, file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: I'm the shinyjs author - there has been no changes to enable/disable, they should still work fine. The code you provided works for me (after adding `library(shiny)` and `library(shinyjs)`)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the downloadhandler in my example. I will add that. In the example, when I change input$in1 and use hide, the download button becomes invisible. When I do the same with disable, there's no visual change to the downloadbutton and when I clicked it the download widow pops up. I might have misunderstood the purpose of disable, but I thought that it wouldn't be possible to use the download function while it the button was disabled.

Comment: Again, your code works fine for me.  Keep in mind that downloading doesn't work properly inside the RStudio Viewer, but in a real web browser it should work. Your code above (the edited version) still works for me

Comment: I was testing on Chrome when this code wasn't responding properly... I just tried in another computer and it's working... Do you think it could related to the package/Shiny version? They are not up to date for certain reasons...

Comment: That's probably the reason, though honestly I don't see why such simple code wouldn't work with older versions

Comment: Just got shinyjs updated and the code is working. Thank you for your help and sorry for the trouble.